# Array in apps script not working as I expected

Tags: google-apps-script, multidimensional-array

When I debug this code I see values in the parent array (thisArray) are changing while the code is NOT executing the "thisArray =" code. I have included a simple version of code that replicates the problem I am having.

the results I am expecting in thisArray

```
["Pass # 1","this is some data"]
["Pass # 2","this is some data"]
["Pass # 3","this is some data"]
```

the results I get

```
["Pass # 3","this is some data"]
["Pass # 3","this is some data"]
["Pass # 3","this is some data"]
```

My code

```
function debugThis(){
  var thisArray = [];
  var thisRow = [];
  var pass = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    pass++;
    thisRow[0] = 'Pass # ' + pass;
    thisRow[1] = 'This is some data';
    thisArray[i] = thisRow;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yikes, this did not format the way I intended, my apologies. I guess I need to learn HTML in order to post here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
function debugThis () {

 var thisArray = [];

 for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {

  thisArray.push([`Pass # ${i}`,`This is some data`]);

 }
 
 console.log(thisArray);

}
```

The result of this is:

```
[ [ 'Pass # 1', 'This is some data' ],
  [ 'Pass # 2', 'This is some data' ],
  [ 'Pass # 3', 'This is some data' ] ]
```

Comment: Thank you Matias, I will do it that way.

Comment: I am glad my answer helped you sort out the issue @glenn . When a post's answer solves the problem, it's a good idea for the person who asked the question to mark it as the correct answer. It helps others who might face the same problem later on.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the same result for each element of the array is because you are defining an array `thisRow` outside the loop.  So within the loop you are filling `thisArray` with 3 references to `thisRow` and changing the values of `thisRow` from 1 to 2 to 3 so only the last value is stored in `thisRow`.  Instead move the creation of `thisRow` into the loop.

```
function debugThis(){
  var thisArray = [];
  var pass = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    pass++;
    let thisRow = [];  // creates a new array different from the previous
    thisRow[0] = 'Pass # ' + pass;
    thisRow[1] = 'This is some data';
    thisArray[i] = thisRow;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I'm pretty new to apps script and defining arrays has been challenging.